# Can I go to Croatia with a type C, multiple entrances Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, croatia

I bought a flight to Croatia for the first of June of this year (2015) As Croatia is still not part of the Schengen States, can I still go to Croatia and then go back to the Schengen space?

Comment: If you already have a multiple-entry Schengen visa, what's the problem?

Comment: Are you asking if your Schengen visa is sufficient to enter Croatia?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> Aliens who are holders of:
>
> - uniform visa (C) for two or multiple entries, valid for all Schengen
>     Area Member States;
> - visa with limited territorial validity (LTV visa),
>     for two or multiple entries, issued to the holder of a travel document
>     that is not recognised by one or more, but not all of the Schengen
>     Area Member States, and which is valid for the territory of the Member
>     States recognising the travel document;
> - long-stay visa (D) for stays
>     exceeding three months, issued by one of the Schengen Area Member
>     State;
> - residence permit issued by one of the Schengen Area Member
>     State;
> - national visas for two or multiple entries and residence
>     permits of Bulgaria, listed in Annex I of the Decision No 565/2014/EU;
> - national visas for two or multiple entries and residence permits of
>     Cyprus, listed in Annex III of the Decision No 565/2014/EU;
> - national
>     visas for two or multiple entries and residence permits of Romania,
>     listed in Annex IV of the Decision No 565/2014/EU;
>
> do not require a
>   visa for transit or intended stays in the territory of Croatia not
>   exceeding 90 days in any 180-day period.

http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/